# metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL() returns nil

Tags: swift, firebase, metadata, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download an url to store in my database but the new update in Firebase prohibits me from doing this by requiring me to use the new way to download urls. Here's my code:

```
 let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
 let storageRef = storage.reference().child("project_images").child("\(imageName)")

    guard let uplodaData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) else {
        return
    }


    let uploadTask = storageRef.putData(uplodaData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

        if error != nil{
            print(error ?? "Failed to upload data in the uploadImages object there was an error:", error!)
            return
        }
```

If I put a breakpoint here it doesn't continue past the next section, I don't know why. I normally see these problems when storing in the wrong node or something.

```
metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in


        if error != nil {
            print("Failed to download url:", error!)
            return
        }

        let url = "\(String(describing: url))"
        uploadedImageUrlsArray.append(url)

        uploadCount += 1
        if uploadCount == imagesCount{
            completionHandler(uploadedImageUrlsArray)
        }
    })
})
```

When I but a breakpoint I can inspect the error variable in the completion and it's nil.

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you be clearer about where you are putting the breakpoints?  Do you ever reach `let url = "\(String(describing: url))"`

Comment: @Kayla Galway no, I can't get passed "metadata?.storageReference?.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in" at all

Comment: have you checked if metadata is nil before that point yet?

Comment: Yes, it's not nil

Comment: `metadata?.storageReference` is also not nil?

Comment: The metadata from the uploadTask isn't nil. Here is the console print: Optional(FIRStorageMetadata 0x60000012b360: {
    bucket = "projectsupportermark2.appspot.com";
    contentDisposition = "inline; filename*=utf-8''8DE05116-776C-4CEE-93D0-24FDD5875B68";
    contentEncoding = identity;
    contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    generation = 1527185706861061;
    md5Hash = "4T6QHmoZu4SJL2AroyS8Vw==";
    metageneration = 1;
    name = "project_images/8DE05116-776C-4CEE-93D0-24FDD5875B68";
    size = 480642;
    timeCreated = "2018-05-24T18:15:06.826Z";
    And so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You created a storage reference for this specific image, so use that instead of `metadata?.storageReference`.

```
storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in


    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download url:", error!)
        return
    }

    let url = "\(String(describing: url))"
    uploadedImageUrlsArray.append(url)

    uploadCount += 1
    if uploadCount == imagesCount{
        completionHandler(uploadedImageUrlsArray)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for your patience with me!

Comment: I had the same problem, and this resolved it, but I do not think I fully understand why. Thanks!